# Simulate higher screen resolution because I want to ZOOM IN later using screen capture software (like Camtasia)

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, video-editing, camtasia

I'm recording tutorials for audio software and I always find myself zooming in on details when editing the screen captures.
As a result, the zooming-ini parts have a bad resolution and look blurred.

The max screen resolution for my monitor is 1920x1080 and I'm using a GeForce GTX 750 TI graphic card.

Is there a way to record at a simulated higher 2K screen resolution?
My goal is to achieve better quality/resolution when zoooming in 180% when using the screen capture software.

Is the only way to record at a higher resolution to buy a 2K monitor?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NVIDIA Control Panel:

Go to display > change resolution

Under the resolution options, click Customize

Click Create Custom Resolution

Add your resolution which is bigger than your monitor

You can now selection that resolution from the "choose your resolution" box. If it's not there, try closing and opening nvidia control panel.

Now you can record at high res. Note that everything will be shrunk unless you also adjust the display scaling in windows, or in the software you're recording (in my case it was just a website, which is easy to zoom into).

I used OBS to record and it seemed to work.

Comment: To unlock higher screen resolutions, you must first enable "Dynamic Super Resolution" in the 3D settings. See [this answer for the details](https://superuser.com/a/1680647/120155).

Answer (score -1):

1920x1080 should be enough to suffice zooming in without a loss of quality. You need to try using other screen capture softwares like Fraps or OBS Studio because the one you're using right now is failing to capture everything with minimal blurriness while zooming in.

You mention simulated 2K screen resolution but this simply isn't possible because of the restraints of your monitor. It's almost hinting at AI upscaling.. which, alas, isn't in the mainstream yet :P

Your resolution, as-is, is absolutely fine. There is no need to spend a lot of money on a 2K monitor. Try using other programs like I mentioned. [OBS is free.](https://obsproject.com/)

Comment: 1080 is not enough for zooming, because it's the same resolution as the video... any zooming in will cause blurring.

Comment: @stackers fine, use a [Virtual Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1120476/how-do-i-simulate-a-higher-resolution-than-screens-maximum-resolution-on-window)